# Can I use a USA Visa issued to me in India to travel from Australia

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, australia, b1-b2-visas

I hold an Indian passport and I have a USA B1/B2 visa that was issued to me in India last year. The visa is valid for 10 years but I recently moved from India to Australia for higher studies. I wanted to know if the visa I got in India is still valid and can I use to travel from Australia to USA or do I have to apply for a new visa in Australia to travel to the US?

Answer (score 9):

Noone cares where you enter from. I used my ten year multi entry visa into the USA in my Hungarian passport uncounted times over the years while I resided in Canada. They do care about whether you are a genuine visitor but that's it.

Comment: But your visa was issued in Canada, wasn't it?

Comment: Nope, Budapest, Hungary, before I immigrated. And I was still using that visa in the expired passport when I got a new Hungarian passport. I only stopped when I got a Canadian passport.